# GitHub Actions dotnet publish Specify a project with a Dot in the name

Tags: github-actions, maui, dotnet-publish

I am setting up my CICD for a MAUI app using GitHub actions.  I'm using the dotnet publish command to publish the application but if I have a "." in the name of the project it can't find the project.

```
- name: Build
  run: dotnet publish AppTest.Maui/AppTest.Maui.csproj
```

Gives me the error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

I've verified it's the period in the name, if I rename the project to AppTest it works fine

```
- name: Build
  run: dotnet publish AppTest/AppTest.csproj
```

I have tried using "_" instead of a "." as well as several variations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I just need to know the correct way to refer to a project w/ a "." in the name...

Edit To Include final answer:

```
dotnet publish "AppTest.Maui/AppTest.Maui.csproj"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't MSBuild build a project with a dot in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863043/why-wont-msbuild-build-a-project-with-a-dot-in-the-name)

Comment: The above thread suggests replacing dots with underscores in the `target` name. You might need to configure it somehow e.g. in the project properties or from the command line.

Comment: That's the article i used as a reference for trying it with "_" instead of "." but i didn't have any luck.  I also dont see that target is an option for the dotnet publish command:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild, "**The `dotnet publish` command accepts MSBuild options, such as `-p` for setting properties**". And, `msbuild` switches here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022#switches.

Comment: According to above docs, something like this `dotnet publish -p:target=<target> <solution>` should work. You need to test it though on your side.

Comment: sorry i put the above name incorrectly, i meant i was trying to point at a specific project. AppTest.Maui.csproj

so are you saying it would look like this? 
dotnet publish -p:AppTest_Maui AppTest_Maui.csproj

Comment: Like this: `dotnet publish -p:target=AppTest_Maui AppTest.Maui.csproj` (underscore in `target` and the project name as is).

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for the help, but I wasn't able to get the target to work.  I did however figure out that if you wrap it in quotes that it does work.  

Final Solution: 
dotnet publish "AppTest.Maui/AppTest.Maui.csproj"

Comment: Good to hear that. Then, it's something else. Did you find out the reason why doesn't work without quotes? Does it work locally without quotes? You might want to edit your answer and add some more details for future readers.

Comment: It’s possible that there’s a way to get it to work using target but I tried many combinations and each time I had to wait for my pipeline to finish so it was pretty difficult to troubleshoot.  I ended up making a pipeline in azure devops using the UI to setup a build task so I could see how that handled pointing at a project with a . and when it ran the output I noticed it used quotes which ended up solving my issue…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Answer:

```
dotnet publish "AppTest.Maui/AppTest.Maui.csproj"
```